# how to solve this error : Download mode successfully detected, but getting no sync reply The serial TX path seems to be down. while connecting gps esp

Tags: gps, esp32, gsm

I have to connect gps to esp32 by Arduino ide code. But i am getting this error : fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Download mode successfully detected, but getting no sync reply: The serial TX path seems to be down.
How to solve this error aand make sure the location to be displayed in serial monitor

I tried removing rx and tx pins and uploaded the code. The error didn't appear but the output didn't come in serial monitor

Answer (score 0):

check if the TX or RX traces/pins are connected up properly, maybe you accidentally scratched a trace on your board or something like that which causes the TX pin to be unavailable to the programming chip